# How to redirect stdout and stderr to a pipe but keep them ordered

Tags: python, unix, file-io, posix, pipe

I want to be able to read independently the stdout/stderr (and a new stdlog I am introducing) from a sub-process, do something with these streams, and write them to the screen and to a log file in the same order.

So, for example, if the sub-process wants to say "aa" to stdout, then "bb" to stderr and then "cc" to stdout again, I want to see "aabbcc" on screen. If I see "aaccbb", I can tolerate it (I guess it can't be helped), but I would certainly not want to see "aacbbc" (something written in one bug chunk "cc" being split).

So, here is the process hierarchy I came up with:

```
(P) parent process
\_ (O) logger for stdout
\_ (E) logger for stderr
\_ (C) monitored process
```

- (C) stdout is connected using a pipe to (O) process that write to a logfile and to the stdout
- (C) stderr is connected using a pipe to (E) process that write to a logfile and to the stderr

The problem is that depending on when (O) and (E) are scheduled, the general output (composed of the output of (O) and (E)) can be out of order.

Is there a way I can:

- have perfect ordering? I guess no but perhaps there is a solution ...
- at least know exactly how many bytes to read in the (O) and (E) processes so I could get them in one piece?

And, preferably using python, and portable across unices.

Note: the code is on [github](https://github.com/mildred/redo/). The whole idea is to capture the exact output of the monitored process, store it in a log file. Write in the log file markers such as "\0err\0" or "\0std\0" before writing output from stderr or stdout so I can later regenerate the exact output from the process, respecting stdout and stderr.

Thank you

Comment: The ordering of these things is somewhat hard to predict.  Specifically, frequently `stdout` will be buffered whereas `stderr` won't be.  Thus, depending on the buffer size, you could get a different order when running the same program with the same inputs.

Comment: Probably not too helpful, but: "If I see "aaccbb", I can tolerate it" --- that's why logger programs tend to log stdout completely separately from stderr, so you always end up with "aaccbb", i.e. all stdout first, and all stderr afterwards.  I think there is no better way, short of making changes in the source code of the process C.  (Terminals connect the same pipe to stdout and stderr, which works, but has the effect that the terminal can't distinguish stdout from stderr at all.)

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect stdout and stderr to the same pipe (i.e. `proc1 2>&1 | proc2`) then you can't control the order on the pipe because they're now exactly the same.  Both stdout and stderr have the same path inside the operating system.

The order in which "proc2" will read the data depends only on the order in which "proc1" writes them.  *That* order is dependent only on proc1.

Typically, a process will buffer data like this:

- **stdout** is buffered but flushes every newline if the output is a TTY, otherwise when the buffer is full.
- **stderr** is unbufferred and always immediately flushes with every write.

You can mess with the python buffers or make stdout and stderr be the exact same thing but perhaps the easiest way would be to try `python -u ...` to make all output be unbufferred.  With that, each write from proc1 should appear at proc2 in the same order.